# pcntl_async_signals() has been disabled for security reasons || Ubuntu 16 - Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, laravel-5.6, php-7.2, pcntl

I have a server running on Ubuntu 16.04 running Laravel app version 5.6.29 on PHP version 7.2.8.

I have set up some queue jobs to upload videos to the server and compile them and upload to s3 bucket. Suddenly from the past few hours,I am facing the following issue.

> pcntl_async_signals() has been disabled for security reasons

I have also tried the solution from this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/16262922
It's not helping either.

[image]

---

Edit : I also tried restarting queue worker, Running the queue worker manually. Also tried restarting supervisorctl.

```
sudo supervisorctl restart all
php artisan queue:restart
php artisan queue:work
```

Comment: It's odd to say the least that the requirement of the pcntl extension and manually enabling its functions is not mentioned anywhere in the Horizon documentation.

Comment: @JItendra Rana mark as correct the 1st awnser

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check your php.ini configuration. You'll find a line:

```
disable_functions = pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid........
```

You'll need to remove any functions that are called by the queue driver, such as pcntl_async_signals, pcntl_async_signals, pcntl_alarm, pcntl_signal.

Comment: Thanks. :) On Ubuntu, I had to make this adjustment in multiple php.ini configurations. Had adjusted the php-fpm configuration and it still failed, until I adjusted the CLI one too. My paths:
`/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini` and `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini`